# How to get voucher list of a specific voucher type in tally via soap request

Tags: xml

I am trying to get Tally Erp 9 Ledger through XML Request , everything is working fine. i got voucherlist but i need  specific voucher type from that list.

```
    <ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
     <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
   <ID>Day Book</ID>
    </HEADER>
  <BODY>
  <DESC>
 <STATICVARIABLES>
  <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">dd-MMM-yyyy</SVFROMDATE>
    <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">dd-MMM-yyyy</SVTODATE>
   <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
          <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
      </STATICVARIABLES>
     <TDL>
       <TDLMESSAGE>
         <COLLECTION NAME="Day Book" ISMODIFY="No">
      <TYPE>VoucherType</TYPE>
      <FETCH>Name,Parent</FETCH>

        <FILTERS>VTYPE</FILTERS>

        </COLLECTION>

             <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="VTYPE">

          </SYSTEM>


            </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
             </DESC>
               </BODY>
             </ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: soap request to get voucherlist

Comment: you should include the code you tried, otherwise no one can help you. please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and note that this community is for specific programming-related questions.

Comment: i edit it ?help me

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
    <ID>Voucher Register</ID>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <DESC>
      <STATICVARIABLES>
      <VoucherTypeName>Sales</VoucherTypeName>
      </STATICVARIABLES>
    </DESC>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```